# Hibernate Issuing Individual queries instead of joining

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an application where i am using Hibernate and JPA.  I have 2 objects (order and product).  They join together and i can get the information i want but its actually issuing 1 query to get all my orders, i get a bunch of queries in my logs to find the product information.  I have tried all sorts of annotations but cannot get it to work properly.  Any help with this would be great.

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class ProductFeedback implements ProductFeedbackInterface {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(columnDefinition="INT")
private Long id;
private String decision;
private String reportId;
...
@ManyToOne
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumn(name = "sku", referencedColumnName = "sku", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Product product;
```

When i try to query for this table  i get somethign like the following queries:

```
Hibernate: select top 50 productfee0_.id as id1_1_... from product_feedback productfee0_ where 1=1 and productfee0_.date_reported_date>=? and productfee0_.date_reported_date<=? and (productfee0_.decision=? or productfee0_.decision is null) and (productfee0_.dtype=? or productfee0_.dtype=?) and (productfee0_.severity in (0) or productfee0_.dtype<>?) order by productfee0_.date_reported_date desc

Hibernate: select ... from product product0_ where product0_.sku=?
Hibernate: select ... from product product0_ where product0_.sku=?
```

EDIT::: I have tried using @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) also with no luck.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

We are using specifications to build the query:

```
public List<ProductFeedback> findAll(ProductFeedbackFilters     productFeedbackFilters) {

    Page recordsPage = jpaRecordRepository.findAll(buildSpecifications(productFeedbackFilters), sortPageable(productFeedbackFilters.getLimit()));
    return recordsPage.getContent();
}
```

Here is a sample...

```
private Specifications<ProductFeedback> defaultSpecifications() {
    return where((queryRoot, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        return criteriaBuilder.and(new Predicate[]{}); // Always true
    });
}

private Specification<ProductFeedback> buildSpecifications(ProductFeedbackFilters filters) {
    return new RecordSpecificationsBuilder(filters)
            .onOrAfterStartDate()
            .onOrBeforeEndDate()
            .status()
            .type()
            .userQuery()
            .severity()
            .keyword()
            .build();
}


public ProductFeedback findByReturnIdentifier(Integer catalogNumber, String commentType) {
    return jpaRecordRepository.findOne((queryRoot, query, criteriaBuilder) ->
            criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(queryRoot.get("catalogNumber"), catalogNumber), criteriaBuilder.equal(queryRoot.get("commentType"), commentType)));
}
```

Comment: How are you running the query? Can you put the code related to that ?

Comment: we are building specifications  and passing it to the findAll() method.  Please see the edit at the bottom for more detail

Answer (score 2):

You can tell the persistence provider to fetch the `ProductFeedback.product` relation with your queried `Product` entites, so the simple query for `ProductFeedback` objects

```
SELECT pf FROM ProductFeedback pf
```

would become

```
SELECT pf FROM ProductFeedback pf LEFT JOIN FETCH pf.product
```

With criteria query, assuming you already have a `Root<ProductFeedback>` object, you can tell to eagerly fetch the associated `ProductFeedback.product` object with the following:

```
productFeedbackRoot.fetch("product", JoinType.LEFT);
```

or if you have your [JPA static metamodel classes generated](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html):

```
productFeedbackRoot.fetch(ProductFeedback_.product, JoinType.LEFT);
```

Comment: I dont have a root object, and honestly i'm not too experienced with this so i am not sure what you mean... :/  Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Those are alternative ways to specify the FETCH JOIN to the query in case you're using the [JPA Criteria API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjrij.html) instead of [JPQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language). In contrast with the JPQL, the Criteria API, though more complex, allows you to specify queries in a programmatic way instead of building a string with the query expression, possibly guarranteeing type safety in case you're using the JPA static metamodel classes as well. If you're only using JPQL, go with the first example.

Comment: I can now see your updated question with some of your query code. The root object in my example would be the `queryRoot` in your question or something similar, representing the `from ProductFeedback` part in a JPQL query.

Comment: so we never actually define queryRoot, query, or criteriaBuilder.  I am not sure exactly how to do this.  We jsut do this in the builder:

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of persistency wrapper you are using around JPA, but the underlying JPA should work the same. Try invoking the `queryRoot.fetch("product", JoinType.LEFT);` in an appropriate place and see what happens. Make sure the code actually executes.

Comment: public RecordSpecificationsBuilder(ProductFeedbackFilters productFeedbackFilters) {
        this.productFeedbackFilters = productFeedbackFilters;
        this.recordSpecifications = new RecordSpecifications();
        this.specifications = emptySpecifications();
    }

    private Specifications<ProductFeedback> emptySpecifications() {
        return where((queryRoot, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            return criteriaBuilder.and(new Predicate[]{}); // Always true
        });
    }

Comment: Try adding it to the closure before the return statement.

Comment: this is what we did: 
private Specifications<ProductFeedback> emptySpecifications() {
        return where((queryRoot, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            queryRoot.fetch("product", JoinType.LEFT);
            return criteriaBuilder.and(new Predicate[]{}); // Always true
        });
    }

Comment: this is giving us the error: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list

Comment: I'm not sure how I could further help you. You seem to be using some custom, probably in-house wrapper around the JPA API, and I can't possibly have any knowledge how that works. Regarding the error message, it tells you that you try to join fetch the association `product`, but the owner of the association, `ProductFeedback` is not present in the select list. Maybe you're fetching only some attributes of the `ProductFeedback` entity? In the `buildSpecifications` method, aren't you actually limit the selection to **some** of the properties of `ProductFeedback` instead of the whole entity?

Comment: So i added queryRoot.join("product", JoinType.LEFT); and we started to get the query to do the proper left join.  What i do notice is that the query actually doesnt select the fields from the product table. Also the individual queries against the product table are being fired.

Comment: Note that I said `productFeedbackRoot.fetch("product", JoinType.LEFT);` not `productFeedbackRoot.join("product", JoinType.LEFT);`.

Comment: Yes but when we do that, thats when we get the error "owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list".  How else do you add those columns other than having the product object nested in the productfeedback object?

Comment: No. The problem is that you probably select only individual columns of the `ProductFeedback` entity, and not the whole entity. Not sure where that happens but my best guess would be the `buildSpecifications` method. It might be somewhere else just as well. I have no means to tell you where that happens as 1) you are using a custom wrapper 2) the code you posted is incomplete. Maybe there's someone in your company who actually wrote the wrapper code that could better help you.

Answer (score 1):

The fetching strategy is determined by the default behavior of hibernate which is ***explained in its documentation like this*** ..

*The fetch strategy defined in the mapping document affects:

retrieval via get() or load()

retrieval that happens implicitly when an association is navigated

Criteria queries

HQL queries if subselect fetching is used
Irrespective of the fetching strategy you use, the defined non-lazy graph is guaranteed to be loaded into memory. 
***This might, however, result in several immediate selects being used to execute a particular HQL query.***
Usually, the mapping document is not used to customize fetching. Instead, we keep the default behavior, and override it for a particular transaction, using left join fetch in HQL. This tells Hibernate to fetch the association eagerly in the first select, using an outer join. In the Criteria query API, you would use setFetchMode(FetchMode.JOIN).
If you want to change the fetching strategy used by get() or load(), you can use a Criteria query. For example:

```
User user = (User) session.createCriteria(User.class)
            .setFetchMode("permissions", FetchMode.JOIN)
            .add( Restrictions.idEq(userId) )
            .uniqueResult();
```

This is Hibernate's equivalent of what some ORM solutions call a "fetch plan".*

**The key is that hibernate expects the fetch mode to be set at transaction level.**